# Open source code for cast shadow detection and removal

Tags: c++, .net, opencv, image-processing

I have implemented foreground subtraction to detect moving cars and the results look pretty good. The only issue is in removing the shadows , which form a part of the foreground.

I searched online to find a way to fix this and found links to many papers :

1) Moving Shadow Detection with Low- and Mid-Level Reasoning

2)J.-F. Lalonde, A. A. Efros, and S. G. Narasimhan. Detecting Ground Shadows 
in Outdoor Consumer Photographs. in European Conference on Computer Vision, 
2010.

[Please watch the video](http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=744441)
 for a better idea of what I am looking for. Though the papers make for great learning, they are beyond my level of comprehension at this point. Could someone point me to some open source code which could help me understand and implement shadow removal?

Comment: As far as I know, using TWO cameras and OpenCV you can get "depth" of the scene which will make elimintation of shadows easier. Check this article: http://www.hornallanderson.com/blog/what-the-hax-a-homebrew-kinect-sorta

Answer (score 0):

See the following paper, which contains links to the source code for various shadow detection/removal algorithms:

A. Sanin, C. Sanderson, B.C. Lovell. "Shadow Detection: A Survey and Comparative Evaluation of Recent Methods", Pattern Recognition, Vol. 45, No. 4, pp. 1684-1695, 2012.

Official version at:
http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2011.10.001

There is also a pre-print of the above paper on the Arxiv server: http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1233